# launching FocusManager.parse_for_input on DOM mutation event

Tags: dom, dom-manipulation

I see the following

> launching FocusManager.parse_for_input on DOM mutation event

displayed in Google Chrome console after I've run the script manipulating the DOM (basically sorting a table by changing row sequence). Is this a problem that I need to take care of?

Answer (score 5):

seems like it's generated by Kaspersky antivirus browser extension. Nothing bad I guess, except performance issues

Comment: True. Disappeared after Kaspersky was switched off. Thanks.